# Selenium, issue getting ID of a generic tag and clicking

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Issue: I cannot get a clickable variable that points the chosen anime title. The title is an  tag that has a  tag that contains the anime name.
What I want to do is:
1)Get all anime that appear from the website
2)Select the anime that has the same name as the input variable "b"
3)Get the chosen anime title clickable to redirect to its page and datascrape it.

What is causing me a lot of issues is the selection of the right anime, because all anime titles only share the same class name and the "presence of the strong tag" and that doesn't seem enough to get the title clickable

[Website I use selenium on:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovPCg.png)

This is the full program code for the moment:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

```
a = input("Inserisci l'anime che cerchi:  ")
b = str(a)

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://myanimelist.net/anime.php")
print(driver.title)

'''CHIUDIAMO LA FINESTRA DEI COOKIE, CHE NON MI PERMETTE DI PROSEGUIRE COL 
PROGRAMMA'''
puls_cookie = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-47sehv")
puls_cookie.click()

search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 
"/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/input")
time.sleep(2)
search.click()
search.send_keys(b)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
search2 = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "strong")
i = 0

link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"// a[contains(text(),\{b})]")      
# the a represents the <a> tag and the be represents your input text
link.click()

time.sleep(10)

driver.quit()
```

I wanted to open the page by clicking the blue name of one of the anime that came up as result of the previus input on the searchbar

I AM VERY SORRY IF THIS EDIT DOESN'T STILL MAKE THE ISSUE CLEAR, english is not my native lenguage and I'm pretty new to programming too so its very difficult for me.
I thank everyone that spent and (I wish) will spend time trying to help me; God bless you all

Comment: Are you trying to get the name of the anime?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as screenshot(s)? On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: I'm sorry if I uploaded my question badly, this is my first time in here and I forgot to read the full rulebook. If the help that I got with the 2 comments below is enough.. I will just close this thread and that would be the end of it. If I will still need help, I will update the question as you suggested. Sorry again if I made it even harder to help me, I wish you a great day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify index when you use `for in`.

```
#wrong usage
for element in search2:
     anime = search2[i].text

#proper usage
f or element in search2:
     anime = element.text
```

if you want to go to the page of the first anime that comes up as a result of the search

you can use code like this

```
anime = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='js-scrollfix-bottom-rel']/article/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[1][text()='Date A Live']")
driver.get(anime.get_attribute("href"))
```

Since we will no longer be looking for an element instead of a list, we can search it directly in `driver.get` without assigning it to a variable.

```
driver.get(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='js-scrollfix-bottom-rel']/article/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[1][text()='Date A Live']").get_attribute("href"))
```

You can call the link in the 'href' element found in the anime result with the [get_attribute](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get_attribute-element-method-selenium-python/) method

When the element is searched before it is loaded, an error is received because the element is not found. For this, [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) is used, which is waiting for the element to be loaded.

```
anime = "Date A Live"
driver.get(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//div[@class='js-scrollfix-bottom-rel']/article/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[1][text()='{anime}']"))).get_attribute("href"))


driver.get("https://myanimelist.net/anime.php")
searchBar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='q']")
anime = "Date A Live"
searchBar.send_keys(anime)
searchBar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.get(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/a[strong='{anime}']"))).get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: The issue is that I don't want the first anime that comes up but the one that matches what I put in the search bar (most likely the first but it is not guaranteed). Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: I changed it to be according to the searched word in the search results (I did the xpath directly because you did the search directly as "Date A Live". You can assign the searched word to a variable and add it as a variable to xpath.)

Comment: Good evening! I tried your method and I get the error:                                                                raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='js-scrollfix-bottom-rel']/article/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[1][text()='Date A Live']"}

Comment: The element you are looking for may not be loaded. I fixed the code to wait until the element is loaded, can you try this? I added the link about webdriverwait, but if you have any questions, you can ask.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
line 36, in <module>
    driver.get(WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//div[@class='js-scrollfix-bottom-rel']/article/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[1][text()='{anime}']"))).get_attribute("href"))
  File "C:\Users\theni\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 87, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: I am sorry, I tried to change the timings a little and look if something else in the program creates a problem but I can't find anything. I am sorry that I cannot help you and I am sooo grateful for your willingness to get this done.

Comment: I was redirected to a different page than you because I did the search from myanimelist's homepage. It's my fault. I shared the correct code

Comment: EUREKA! It finally works!!!!!! I cannot thank you enough, I wish you a great day

Comment: @JustAMan glad it worked. As I said, we were having problems because we were searching from different places, I'm sorry for not noticing this earlier. If there is no problem with the code working, can you mark the answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because driver.find_elements() returns a list, even if it only finds one element. You are probably getting an error like: 'list' object has no attribute 'Click'

I think an easier way would be to find the element whose text matches your input string. The driver.find_element_by_xpath() method can do this. The If your input string is stored in the variable `b` you could do this with something like:

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"// a[contains(text(),\{b})]") # the a represents the <a> tag and the be represents your input text
link.Click()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that looks like what I was searching for! I will let you know as soon as possible if it fixes my issue

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. I get an error that says this:                                      
                                                
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression // a[contains(text(),\Date A Live)] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '// a[contains(text(),\Date A Live)]' is not a valid XPath expression.